# Deploying websites in django virtual machine

Tags: python, django, postgresql, deployment, web-deployment

Sorry I'm new to this specific topic.
I have a website implemented in django and AskBot it also has a DB (postgreSQL). I want to create a deployment package which can be distributed to any customer; such that this customer can have their own server. Taking into consideration that the deployment package should be platform independent; so it should work on all operating systems.
Can you tell me what are the available tools to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

virtualenv is a really good tool but I think Vagrant is what you're looking for.
https://www.vagrantup.com/

It should enable you to easily set up your system regardless of the platform and it's free as well and quite well documented. I'd suggest you give it a look over !

Comment: Thanks it looks really interesting, I'll try it out and if it satisfies what I need, I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, database always should be created before deployment. And the information of the database must be posted to the `settings.py`

for the application it self, I think `virtualenv` can be very helpful in these cases with `requirements.txt`

You run the application in your virtual environment and then export your dependencies using

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Then in the new server you create the database, and insert the configuration in your settings, then install dependences

`pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`

Run migrations, and you are done.

Comment: Can I create a package that includes a virrtual machine with everything on it?

Comment: @PokaYoke you can create a shell script which can create the environment get the packages from your git repo and install dependency.